# How to package a template of a PowerView report inside a SharePoint feature?

Tags: feature, powerview

What we have:

- Project server 2016 on prem, with associated SharePoint sites
- A web part that performs metric calculations based on tasks in
  Project data stored in Project Server.  This web part is deployed to
  a site collection web part gallery through a Site scoped feature.  It
  is thus available to be deployed to any page in SharePoint via the
  usual “insert web part” method.
- A content type (deployed to the root of a site collection via a Site
  scoped feature) and a custom list definition & instance (deployed to
  a particular site through a Web scoped feature).  The web part
  mentioned above saves data to this custom list, and it looks for the
  list instance installed on the same site that the web part is on.

What we need:

- A PowerView report embedded in a SharePoint page on a site that looks
  for data from the custom list mentioned above in the same site. 
  (From my understanding, embedding it on a page can be accomplished by
  using a Page Viewer web part and pointing it at a PowerView report
  stored in a document library on a site.)
- A way to reliably deploy this report to multiple sites.

What we don’t understand:

- How to create a PowerView report as a template and package it in a
  Web scoped feature that can be deployed at the site level, across
  multiple independent sites.
- How do we get the report to look for data from the custom list on the
  same site?  Is there a way to use site relative URLs?  Or are we going to have to use a feature receiver to hard code a full URL based
  on the URL of the site where the feature is being activated?
- Do we need to use an .rsds data source, or will the data source be
  embedded within the .xlsx report?  Is there a way to package an .rsds
  data source in a feature for deployment?