# ADO.NET Data Services for SharePoint 2016?

Tags: 2016, excel, excel-services, powerpivot

As I was asking [in a related question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/246958/8992), I'm trying to figure out how to get a PowerView report going that is using a SharePoint list as its data source.

In researching how that can be done, I found [this q&a on the MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0c5b2945-0c10-4fd1-b938-ce813fa9f21c/how-create-animated-power-view-reports-using-sharepoint-list-as-a-data-source-in-sharepoint-2010?forum=sqlreportingservices) that says

> Currently, Power View report only supports two types of data models:
>   PowerPivot Worksheet, and data models based on Analysis Services
>   Tabular Model or Multidimensional Cube.
>
> In your scenario, you can create PowerPivot worksheets using
>   SharePoint List as data source, deploy the PowerPivot worksheet to a
>   SharePoint Library or PowerPivot Gallery, and then generate Power View
>   reports based on the PowerPivot worksheets on the SharePoint site.

Great!  One step closer.  Then, in researching how to use a SharePoint list as a data source in PowerPivot in Excel, I found multiple articles that say that you have to go to the list you want to use, and click on a button called "Export as Data Feed", like [this one](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/excel_services__powerpivot_for_sharepoint_support_blog/2013/07/11/excel-services-using-a-sharepoint-list-as-a-data-source/) and [this one](https://davidlozzi.com/2012/02/09/powerpivot-walkthrough-using-sharepoint-lists/).  I went to my list, and I *don't* see that button. In researching why that is the case, and how to enable the button, I found articles that say you have to activate the "PowerPivot Feature Integrations for Site Collections" site collection feature.  I went to my site collection features, and the PowerPivot feature *is enabled*.

Then in digging even deeper to find out how everything needs to be configured, I found multiple places, including this [MS whitepaper on the subject](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/hh230322(v=msdn.10)), and also [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/power-pivot-sharepoint/use-data-feeds-power-pivot-for-sharepoint?view=sql-server-2017), that say that in order for the data feeds to work, you need to install ADO.NET Data Services on the SharePoint WFE.

Ok, fine.  But all those resources refer to SharePoint 2010, and everything they link to about ADO.NET Data Services say it's for .NET 3.5.

I'm trying to do this in SharePoint 2016, which is .NET 4.6, which brings us to my question:

Is there an ADO.NET Data Services for .NET 4.6?

Is there some equivalent, maybe with a different name?

How can I get the data feeds working in SP2016 so I can then use a SharePoint list as a data source for a PowerPivot worksheet, which I can *then* in turn use as a data source for a PowerView report?